# How to find the clockwise angle between two vectors in python?

Tags: python-3.x, computational-geometry

I want to find the clockwise angle between two vectors in python
the angle should be in range of (-90,90)

what is the equation/code to calculate the angle ?

```
class Vect:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def findClockwiseAngle(self, other):
    ## how to compute ??
    pass


vector1 = Vect(a1,b1)  ## a1*i + b1*j
vector2 = Vect(a2,b2)  ## a2*i + b2*j
angle = vect1.findClockwiseAngle(vect2)
```

Comment: Try cosine similarity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vector geometry provides (at least) two useful formulas for finding the angle between two vectors:

- the [dot product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

[image]

where `a · b` can be computed using

[image]

- and the [cross-product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning):

[image]

where

[image]

and since our vectors are two dimensional, we can take `a3` and `b3` (the components in the z-axis direction) equal to 0. This simplifies the formula even further:

```
|a x b| = |a1 * b2 - a2 * b1| = |a| * |b| * sin(ϴ)
```

The `ϴ`s is these two formulas, however, have different interpretations.
With the dot product, the angle is the *included angle* between the two vectors -- and thus always a value between 0 and pi.

With the cross product, the angle is measured in the *counterclockwise* direction from `a` to to `b`. Since you are looking for the angle measured in the clockwise direction, you would simply reverse the sign of the angle obtained using the cross product formula.

In Python, `math.asin` returns values in the range [-pi/2, pi/2], whereas `math.acos` returns values in the range [0, pi]. Since you want angles in the range [-pi/2, pi/2] (in radians), the cross-product formula seems to be the more promising candidate:

```
import math

class Vect:

   def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

   def findClockwiseAngle(self, other):
       # using cross-product formula
       return -math.degrees(math.asin((self.a * other.b - self.b * other.a)/(self.length()*other.length())))
       # the dot-product formula, left here just for comparison (does not return angles in the desired range)
       # return math.degrees(math.acos((self.a * other.a + self.b * other.b)/(self.length()*other.length())))

   def length(self):
       return math.sqrt(self.a**2 + self.b**2)

vector1 = Vect(2,0) 

N = 12
theta = [i * 2 * math.pi / N for i in range(N)]
result = []
for t in theta:
    vector2 = Vect(math.cos(t), math.sin(t))  ## a2*i + b2*j
    angle = vector1.findClockwiseAngle(vector2)
    result.append((math.degrees(t), angle))

print('{:>10}{:>10}'.format('t', 'angle'))    
print('\n'.join(['{:>10.2f}{:>10.2f}'.format(*pair) for pair in result]))
```

prints

```
     t     angle
  0.00     -0.00
 30.00    -30.00
 60.00    -60.00
 90.00    -90.00
120.00    -60.00
150.00    -30.00
180.00     -0.00
210.00     30.00
240.00     60.00
270.00     90.00
300.00     60.00
330.00     30.00
```

Above, `t` is the angle from `vector1` to `vector2` measured in the counterclockwise direction in the range (0, 360) degrees. `angle` is the angle from `vector1` to `vector2` measured in the clockwise direction and in the range (-90, 90) degrees.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you want to find the angle in range of (-90,90).
More infomation, you can get the angle in range of (-180,180).
Shown bellow.

From unutbu'answer
You can get cos(theta), sin(theta) of target angle theta.

```
cosTh1 = np.dot(a,b)/(np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(b))
sinTh1 = np.cross(a,b)/(np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(b))
```

You can get tan(theta) = sin(theta)/cons(theta).
In Python, numpy.arctan2 returns values in the range [-pi, pi]. So,

```
print (np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(sinTh1,cosTh1)),end=",")
```

More simple, (cause np.linalg.norm(a)*np.linalg.norm(b) is common.)

```
cosTh = np.dot(a,b)
sinTh = np.cross(a,b)
print (np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(sinTh,cosTh)))
```